# Where is the error in this proof that isosceles triangles do not exist? Hidden division by zero

Tags: vectors, inner-products, fake-proofs

> Where is the error in this proof that isosceles triangles do not exist?

**Given:** $θ=γ$, then:

$$\cos \theta=\cos \gamma$$

$$\frac{u\cdot(u+v)}{||u||||u+v||}=\frac{(-v)\cdot(-(u+v))}{||v||||u+v||}$$
$$\frac{u\cdot u+u \cdot v}{||u||}=\frac{u \cdot v+v \cdot v}{||v||}$$
$$||v||||u||^2+||v||(u\cdot v)=||u||(u\cdot v)+||u||||v||^2$$
$$||u||||v||(||u||-||v||)=(u\cdot v)(||u||-||v||)$$
$$||u||||v||=u\cdot v$$

So the vectors are parallel?
What have I done? This is wrong.

[image: diagram of the vectors showing congruent angles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in your working only holds if $||u|| \neq ||v||$, otherwise you are dividing by $0$ when you perform the simplification:

$$ \big{(}||u||\times||v|| \big{)} \big{(}||u||-||v|| \big{)}=\big{(}u\cdot v\big{)}\big{(}||u||-||v||\big{)}$$ $$ \implies||u|| \times ||v||=u\cdot v$$

Therefore, your working is only valid under the strict assumption that the triangle is not isosceles or equilateral. This type of working can be used to prove anything including [nonsensical statements](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/how-to-prove-that-1-2/) like $1=2$.